# How to store the nested response in a list or dict?

Tags: python, list, dictionary

I have a response:

```
"bid_adjustments": {
    "user_groups": "{\"home_location\":{\"countries\":{\"US\":0.9,\"CA\":0.9},\"default\":0.4}}"
  }
```

I want this response to store as `["US":0.9, "CA":0.9]`.

Comment: Welcome to SO! `json.loads(response["bid_adjustments"]["user_groups"])["home_location"]["countries"]`?

Comment: What specifically is the issue? Please see [ask], [help/on-topic].

Answer (score 0):

there is no syntax in python like `["US":0.9, "CA":0.9]` , maybe you wanted to write something like `{"US": 0.9, "CA": 0.9}` (which is a normal dict), if you want to parse data from string response than you can use json.loads, for more detailes take a look [here](https://docs.python.org/3/library/json.html)